# cakephp paypal plugin - how to do this on windows machine

Tags: shell, cakephp, command-line, paypal

I'm trying to install the paypal plugin for cakephp. It says I should run:

$ cake schema create -path plugins/paypal_ipn/config/sql -name ipn

Which I'm not really sure what that means. If I'm on a windows machine what does that mean I should be doing?

Thanks

Comment: While not directly related to your question, you should not use Paypal. It is easier and better to setup Stripe. There is a couple of CakePHP plugins for it and it is very easy to implement. Secondly, your users stay on your site, when compared to Paypal that they have to go to the Paypal site before returning. Personally I dont like that...

Comment: Or even WePay, although I am not sure if there is a CakePHP plugin for it...

Comment: It's not me who makes the decisions but it's paypal I've been told so paypal it must be. It's a bit of a balls because the docs are absolutely terrible

Comment: I don't suppose you've any idea about the comment I left in the answer below from Martin Bean?

Comment: You should use the following: `cake schema create -path plugins/paypal_ipn/config/sql -name ipn`

Comment: dont include the $ sign per the instruction above... that basically tells you, you need to be in a command line to execute it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s the command line tool for CakePHP. Open up a Command Prompt window, `cd` to the folder in which Cake is in, and enter the above command.

You’ll need to add `cake` to your path first, but I’m not sure how to do that off the top of my head as I’ve been a Mac user the past few years; Google it and you should find how to do so pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've got the path sorted (I can bake now so path defo ok) but I'm getting the error '$' is not recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: Omit the dollar symbol; don’t type it as part of the command. Developers usually use the dollar symbol to differentiate it as a terminal command from “normal” code.